# Setup dense layers to learn from 1D arrays

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, densenet

I have about 100k arrays of size 256 which I would like to input in a neural network composed by few dense layers, and to output 100k arrays of again size 256. (I would like my net to transform the input array into the output array). I cannot manage to set it up correctly.

My `X_train` and `y_train` have shape `(98304, 256)`, my `X_test` and `y_test` `(16384, 256)`.

My network at the moment is

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(256,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='linear'))

optimizer = Adam()
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy', 'mae'])
```

The network actually runs, but it does not give any meaningful result. It stops after 20 epochs because I give it the early stopping.

```
Epoch 00019: val_loss did not improve from -inf
Epoch 20/200
6400/6400 [==============================] - 1s 232us/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.2511 - mean_absolute_error: nan - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.2000 - val_mean_absolute_error: nan
```

And if I try to use it to predict, I only get nan values (I do not have any nan in my training set).

Hope someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
To check whether is a problem with the inputs or the algorithm, I have tried creating my inputs and targets using the following code

```
X_train=[]
y_train=[]

for it in range(1000):
    beginning=random.uniform(0,1)
    end=random.uniform(0,1)
    X_train.append([beginning+(end-beginning)*jt/256 for jt in range(256)])
    y_train.append([end+(beginning-end)*jt/256 for jt in range(256)])
X_train=np.array(X_train)
y_train=np.array(y_train)
```

And I still get

```
Epoch 27/200
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 236us/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.4970 - mean_absolute_error: nan
```

**Edit2**: If I increase the complexity of my network I manage to get a loss different from nan using the 10k training arrays created using the fuction above. However, the results are still quite bad which makes me wonder I am not setting up the network correctly.

The new network:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(256,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2048, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2048, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2048, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='linear'))

optimizer = Adam()
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['mae'])

model.summary()
```

And the result when they converge

```
Epoch 33/200
10000/10000 [==============================] - 23s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0561 - mean_absolute_error: 0.2001 - val_loss: 0.0561 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.2001
```

If I check the output of the network, I always obtain a vector with all points around 0.5 regardless of the input.

[image: Prediction Example]

Also, if I try to predict a single vector using `y_pred=model.predict(Xval[3])` I get the error

```
ValueError: Error when checking : expected dense_27_input to have shape (256,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Comment: Did you normalize your training data?

Comment: Hi @BlackBear , yes the training and test data are both normalized 0 to 1.

Comment: Both inputs and outputs should be normalized. And are you sure there are no `nan`'s in the data?

Comment: @BlackBear yes both inputs and outputs are normalzed and there are not nan in the data. To check whether is a problem with the data or the set up, I have tried using inputs and outputs of type
`Xtmp=[beginning+(end-beginning)*jt/256 for jt in range(256)]` and `ytmp=[end+(beginning-end)*jt/256 for jt in range(256)]` where beginning and end are chosen randmly between 0 and 1, but still I get `nan` values from the net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first layer only has `1` output neuron, this seems wrong. It could be messing up your loss function. Try replacing `model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(256,), activation='relu'))` with `model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(256,)))`.

Comment: Hi Frederik, thanks for your comment. If I try to do so, I get the following error message `The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: Tensor("input_4:0", shape=(None, 256), dtype=float32)`, using Keras version 2.3.1

Comment: `tf.keras.layers.InputLayer` instead of `tf.keras.layers.Input`, my mistake :D I updated my answer.

Comment: Hi Frederik, thank you so much, this solved my issue for simple example shown above. I only needed to use input_shape instead of shape, I have modify your answer in case someone will need this in the future. With my real dataset, however, I still get `nan` values as output of the network. I guess at this point it might be because it is a much harder problem to learn ? Do you have any comments that could help ? Thanks again :)

Comment: No, it's probably your data, but it could be a lot. Check if there are  `nan` values in your dataset. What does `print(np.min(X_train), np.min(y_train), np.max(X_train), np.max(y_train), X_train.dtype, y_train.dtype, X_train.shape, y_train.shape)` give you? It might lead to some clues.

Comment: It was indeed my data, I had a few `nan` I did not manage to remove during my processing of the dataset. It works now. Thank you so much for your help, it was gold